# JNI - multi threads

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, java-native-interface

I have a JNI wrapper for Java functions that are called from C...  I'm trying to call some methods from different threads and I get an error when trying to get a new copy of the JNIEnv pointer... the code I'm using is below and is called in each method:

```
        JNIEnv* GetJniEnvHandle(){
        ThreadInfo();
        JNIEnv *envLoc; 
        //if(Thread::CurrentThread->IsBackground || Thread::CurrentThread->IsThreadPoolThread)  
        jint envRes = vm->GetEnv((void**)&envLoc, JNI_VERSION_1_4);
        if(envRes == JNI_OK){
            if(ThreadId != Thread::CurrentThread->ManagedThreadId)
                jint res = vm->AttachCurrentThread((void**)&envLoc, NULL);
        }else{          
            Log("Error obtaining JNIEnv* handle");  
        }
        return envLoc;
    }
```

The JVM has already been instantiated and this (and other methods) run when being called from the main/initial thread.  When I get a value for envRes it holds a -2 when in a sub-thread.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please refer to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/invocation.html) to the chapter `Attaching to the VM`.

You need to call `AttachCurrentThread()` for each native thread at least once before you can use any of the JNI functions.
Thread created in Java are already attached.
So I your example whenever the `GetEnv` call fails call `AttachCurrentThread()` and you should be fine. Or make sure that whenver you create a sub thread you attach it to the VM.

Comment: that was it - very simple oversight on my part lol.  Just swapped the order of the two JNI calls and it works perfectly! Thanks!