# Use multiple processes in Android gstreamer!!‏

Tags: android, c, stream, gstreamer, pipeline

I'm reading the Android tutorial to `gstreamer`. I'd like to make a simple pipeline from
one android phone to another, [like this](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Android+tutorial+2%3A+A+running+pipeline).
I've read these questions: [loading same gstreamer elements multiple times in a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516511/loading-same-gstreamer-elements-multiple-times-in-a-process/24311296#24311296),
and [JNI - multi threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314645/jni-multi-threads), but they didn't help me resolve my current issue.

I'd like to make two processes to make the android phone send
and receive audio!

On Linux I would use `fork()`, like this:

```
p = fork();
if p==0{
    //pipeline1
}
else {
   //pipeline2
}
```

But this doesn't work on Android, I get this error:

```
{
g_source_set_callback: assertion `source != NULL' failed
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000010 (code=1)
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Using `fork()` is discouraged in NDK, (see: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-platform/80jr-_A-9bU/nkzslcgVrfYJ) as I believe, some variables may get uninitialized, which may be the reason for the assertion error

Comment: I tried with fork and no more error but the second process is not running!! is there another way to do this? is there any one how to work with "runOnUiThread(new Runnable().." to make another process?

Answer (score 0):

With GStreamer you can run 2 pipelines in the same process without having to worry about threading as it's already handled internally.

```
void
start (GError **error) {
  GstElement *pipe1;
  GstElement *pipe2;

  *error = NULL;
  pipe1 = gst_parse_launch ("src ! enc ! mux ! sink", error);
  if (*error != NULL)
    return;
  pipe2 = gst_parse_launch ("src ! demux ! dec ! sink", error);
  if (*error != NULL)
    return;
  gst_element_set_state (pipe1, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  gst_element_set_state (pipe2, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
}
```